# Spinner displays differently than another yet has the same code

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

so I've created 5 spinners on a form. they display numbers and text when clicked but while 3 of them display how I want as they pop up and have a little radio type button next to the currently selected data however 2 of them display as a small list of text. The xml code is

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblInvoiceDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/InvoiceDate" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/InvoiceDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblOrderNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/OrderNumber" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/OrderNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

I have no idea why they display differently even the Java code is exactly the same and I've tried to change the spinner mode, delete the spinner and re-add it. Delete the spinner and copy the one I want.

```
   >ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aInvoiceDate = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        aInvoiceDate.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            for (int i = 0; i < InvoiceDate.length; i++)
            {
                aInvoiceDate.add(InvoiceDate[i]);
            }
            aInvoiceDate.add("Other (User Defined)");
            sInvoiceDate.setAdapter(aInvoiceDate);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aOrderNumber = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        aOrderNumber.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            for (int i = 0; i < OrderNumbers.length; i++)
            {
                aOrderNumber.add(OrderNumbers[i]);
            }
            aOrderNumber.add("Other (User Defined)");
            sOrderNumber.setAdapter(aOrderNumber);
```

Comment: Nice chat... But where's the code?

Comment: Just added the java code

Comment: You named 5 spinners. I only see 2, in both your layout and your code.

Comment: I've only added two because they all have exactly the same code so it would only be more of the same, these two spinners look different but have the same code.

Comment: If they had the very same code, they'd look identical.

Comment: You may wish to upload some screenshots somewhere and link to them from your answer.

Comment: I've fixed the problem by recreating the form and copying the code over then adding android:spinnerMode="dialog" to every spinner. Weird how this didn't work before but thanks for taking some time to help.